# div animation using transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to animate the div when moving from left to right
The div is moving fine but with no animation 
It is very fast 
and more over i have assigned the top and right property to the div when hover but it is not happening

HTML:

```
<body><div></div></body>
```

CSS:

```
div
{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background:red;
   transition-property: right, left;
   transition-duration: 10s;
   -webkit-transition-property: right, left; /* Safari */
   -webkit-transition-duration: 2s; /* Safari */
   transition-timing-function:ease;
   position:absolute;
}

div:hover
{
   right:30px;
   top:10px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3SYka/278/)

I need the div to be moved with ease and slowly

Comment: If you want to "transite" right and top properties, you should define them in unhovered state of element

Answer (score 3):

First you need to define `right` for starting position, e.g `right: calc(100% - 100px);`

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
}
.cube {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
right: calc(100% - 100px);
transition-property: right;
transition-duration: 10s;
-webkit-transition-property: right; /* Safari */
-webkit-transition-duration: 2s; /* Safari */
transition-timing-function:ease;
position:absolute;
}
.wrap:hover .cube
{
right:30px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="cube"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's works

```
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  transition: 1000ms;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
}

div:hover {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3SYka/287/

Answer (score 0):

Replace right,left with margin-left.

```css
div
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
transition-property: margin-left;  
transition-duration: 2s;
-webkit-transition-property: margin-left; /* Safari */
-webkit-transition-duration: 2s; /* Safari */
transition-timing-function:linear;
position:absolute;
}
div:hover
{
margin-left:80%; /* Using margin-left */
top:10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that we can hardware-accelerate graphics-intensive CSS features by offloading them to the GPU for better rendering performance in the browser?

Try to use it, here is an example with `transform`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zso5hsh7/)